# Merge toolstrip MDI child - parent

Tags: c#, winforms, merge, mdi

I found some informations on the internet but nothing helped me out.
How can I merge a toolstrip in the parent mdi form?

Edit:

It worked for me with this code:

```
private void MainForm_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IChildWindow child = ActiveMdiChild as IChildWindow;

    if (child != null)
    {
        ToolStripManager.Merge(child.ToolStrip, toolStrip1);
        child.ToolStrip.Hide();

        child.FormClosing += delegate(object sender2, FormClosingEventArgs fe)
        {
            child.ToolStrip.Show();
            ToolStripManager.RevertMerge(toolStrip1, child.ToolStrip);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `ToolStripManager`. It has a method called `Merge(ToolStrip, ToolStrip)` which does what you want to.
[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.aspx)

For example:

```
ToolStripManager.Merge(((YourChildForm)this.ActiveMdiChild).ToolStrip, parentFormToolStrip);
```

Answer (score 0):

From within the child form one can also perform the following:

```
Private Sub Child_ParentChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ParentChanged
    Try
        ToolStripManager.Merge(Me.ToolStrip, TryCast(sender.mdiParent, frmMain).ToolStrip)
    Catch ex As Exception
        mErrorLog.ApplicationErrorLog(Me.GetType.Name, "frmTechSelectWO_ParentChanged", ex.ToString)
    Finally
        Me.ToolStrip.Hide()
        Me.MenuStrip1.Hide()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Child_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    '
    ' Clean up the parent toolbar
    Try
        ToolStripManager.RevertMerge(TryCast(Me.MdiParent, frmMain).ToolStrip)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```